# JWT authentication on backend or on frontend?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am making my first web application and from my search online I've seen various guides on how to implement JWT authentication and authorization on the backend and the frontend. For the backend I'm using Springboot and for the frontend I'm using Angular. My question is:
Should I choose implementing one of the too, if yes, which one and why, or are both needed to implemented for the web app to work properly?

Answer (score 4):

You should implement it on both backend / frontend.
The Front end should have a UI to get the login / password entered by the user.
The Backend verify these params against your users data on the database:

- If the user exists and the password is correct then the backend generates a JWT token and send back to the frontend.
- On the frontend, you can store this JWT token on the local storage, and use it in the header of the all XHR you send to the backend (only the API calls with a valid JWT token should be accepted by the backend).
  Here you can find a good exemple:
  https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-spring-boot-jwt-auth/

Answer (score 0):

The implementation should be on both sides.

Backend should provide API's to create, refresh, blacklist and retrieve tokens for users.

Frontend should use the token to check if a user is authenticated and send it in every requests, so that the backend can know what user is operating.

Comment: Can I use Keycloak or Auth0 to do this?

Comment: Worth noting that your authentication backend and application backend need not be the same. There are already full auth implementations out there, e.g. auth0 or Keycloak.

Comment: Ah yes, my comment seems to have been a bit quicker into asking that, thanks :D

Comment: Sure you can use both, for personal experience i can say that I enjoy working more with Auth0